# Use PHP CURL to call self Restful APIs hangs forever

Tags: php, session, curl

I want to write a script to call one of my Restful APIs every one hour.

I use Laravel framework.

Here are the codes:

`TestController.php`

```
class TestController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(ItemCriteria $itemCriteria)
    {
        parent::__construct($itemCriteria);
    }

    public function sayHi()
    {
        echo 'hi';
    }

    public function getHi()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/v1/sayhi");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        echo $output;
    }

 }
```

`routes.php`:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function () {
    Route::get('sayhi', 'Api\TestController@sayHi');
    Route::get('gethi', 'Api\TestController@getHi');
}
```

I call `api/v1/gethi`, but the response never comes back. Browse just shows loading.

What I have tried:

Searched on Google, many people say this is due to the session being locked. Therefore, I add the code to close session before `curl_exec`:

```
public function getHi()
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/v1/sayhi");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    session_write_close();

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;

}
```

Sadly, this does not work. I check `phpinfo()`, sessions should not start automatically as per my settings: `session.auto_start Off`.

[image]

I also did a small experiment: made an API `api/vi/sleep`, which forces the thread to sleep for 10 seconds. During this time I call `api/v1/sayhi`, I found it won't respond until first call is finished.

```
public function sleep()
{
    sleep(10);
}
```

I thought this might be Apache thread configuration problem, but all configurations seem fine:

[image]

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

My environment:

- Windows 7 64bit.
- Xampp (Apache 2.4.16; PHP 5.6.12).

I am stuck with this for a few weeks. I don't know that else I can do...

Comment: and what about the router.php  ? maybe it is missing something and not calling the method

Comment: What about keep-alive? Try settings CURL HTTP header `Connection` to value `close`. Probably the server doesn't close connection and waits for more requests: `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Connection: close")); curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);`

Comment: Try to add some logging commands. It may be enough to put just enough of `file_put_contents('/path/to/filename', "sayHi - start", FILE_APPEND);` commands in your app to find out what exactly happens. (This is a more robust library for logging https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog)

Comment: @AndrewDunai I tried adding header and forbin_reuse but got the same result, endless loading. :(

Comment: @MartyIX Add logging commands doesn't help because it always hangs in this line `$output = curl_exec($ch)`

Comment: @Arst Yes, but you want to log *the other request* to find out how far it gets.

Comment: @MartyIX Unfortunately it never runs into `api/v1/sayhi` API. :(

Comment: @Arst: And does it go to index.php at all?

Comment: @MartyIX I just gave it a try, it didn't go to index.php after `$output = curl_exec($ch)`

Comment: So now you know that it's a problem with Apache...

Comment: Have tried different configurations, but still no luck..please help..

Comment: Is apache running on port 8888 or do you have some other server running (like the included php web server)?